# django - how do i use an input from a select form to compare data in my database and output it on another page?

Tags: python, django, select

```
<form method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class = "lookback"
        <label for = "time"></label>
        <select name = "time" id = "time">
            <option value = "today">Today</option>
            <option value = "yesterday">Yesterday</option>
            <option value = "lastweek">Last Week</option>
            <option value = "lastmonth">Last Month</option>
            <option value = "lastyear">Last Year</option>
            <option value = "forever">Forever</option>
        </select>
            <button><a type= "button" class = "Look" id = "look" href = "">Look Back?!</a></button>
        </form>
```

** Above is the portion of HTML page i am using to get the select value so that I can use it in my views.py to filter out the data and output it on another page. **

```
 def retro(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        time = ThoughtForm(request.POST)
        today = timezone.now().date()
        if time == "Yesterday":
            yesterday = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=1)
            data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=yesterday, date__lt=today)
        elif time == "Last Week":
            week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
            data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=week, date__lt=today)
        elif time == "Last Month":
            month = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=30)
            data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=month, date__lt=today)
        elif time == "Last Year":
            year = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=365)
            data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=year, date__lt=today)
        elif time == "Forever":
            data = Thought.objects.all 
        else:
            data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=today, date__lt=today)
    
        return render(request,'look.html', {'data' : data})

    else:
        return render(request, 'retro.html')
```

**When I use the submit button of the retro.html (the one with the select input), it does direct me to the page I want to output my data to. However, it does not print the data in the page.**

```
<div class = "results">
    <form method = "GET" >
        <h1>Till now, you thought of writing- </h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class = "thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <td>Thought</td>
                    <td>Date</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for obj in data%}     
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ obj.thought }}</td>
                    <td>{{ obj.date.date}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Directly above is the html for the page I am trying to output my data in.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

class Thought(models.Model):
    thought = models.CharField( max_length=300)
    done = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    #date = models.models.DateField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.thought) + "-  " + str(self.done)
```

Directly above is my models.py file.

```
from django import forms 
from retrospection.models import Thought

class ThoughtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thought
        fields = ['thought', 'done', 'date']
```

Directly above is my form.py file.

After trying what Blackeagle52 suggested and by printing(form.is_valid()), I found out that my form is failing the is_valid test with an error -

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>thought<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

My form contains a select item with a few options and a submit button. I am not sure how the field can be empty. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, was not active during the weekend. But your html-form is lacking a `thought` and a `date` field, as those are defined in your ThoughtForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def retro(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ThoughtForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            time = form.cleaned_data['time']
            today = timezone.now().date()
            if time == "Yesterday":
                yesterday = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=1)
                data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=yesterday, date__lt=today)
            elif time == "Last Week":
                week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
                data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=week, date__lt=today)
            elif time == "Last Month":
                month = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=30)
                data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=month, date__lt=today)
            elif time == "Last Year":
                year = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=365)
                data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=year, date__lt=today)
            elif time == "Forever":
                data = Thought.objects.all 
            else:
                data = Thought.objects.filter(date__gte=today, date__lt=today)
    
            return render(request,'look.html', {'data' : data})
        # TODO Do something when form is invalid.
        #      Maybe just removing the else below this, so you'll get retro.html
    else:
        return render(request, 'retro.html')
```

To explain my solution, in your code `time` was not a value, but a Form.
To retrieve the data from the form, you first need to check whether the form is valid (`is_valid()`) and than retrieve the value from `form.cleaned_data`.

There are some other minor things you could improve. After a POST, redirect to another view, as now this look.html is only visible on a POST. If you want to refresh that page or something, you'll be back at retro.html.

With the Forever-case, you are also missing `()` on your `.all()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried what you suggested and I'm still facing problems. For some reason I don't know, my form returns False when I print(form.is_valid()) and the error is
 ``` <ul class="errorlist"><li>thought<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>```  
Could you please suggest what to do? I have tried going through previous posts asking similar questions and it didn't work. I am adding my models.py to my question if it helps paint a clear picture for you.